# SharePoint Syntex - Configuration Content Assembly Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, microsoft

While configuring the content assembly from admin center setup for all libraries in all SharePoint Sites, we received a **"Something went wrong. Please try again later" message.**
[image]

We have already configured Syntex's pay-as-you-go pricing model.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/syntex/content-assembly

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/syntex/content-assembly-setup

Please advise if we missed anything in the configuration.

Any help is greatly appreciated.